# Java Script is not checking the form

Tags: javascript

That is the thing.

My head:

```
<script  language="JavaScript">
    function checkIt(){
        var pass = document.form1.value;  
        if (pass == "1234")  
            {  
                alert("Please input a Value");  
                return false;  
            }  
        else   
            {  
                alert('Code has accepted : you can try another');  
                return true;   
            }  
    } 
window.onload = checkIt();
</script>
```

My body:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form1" onsubmit="checkIt();">
    <input type="password" id="sn" name="sn" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
<img src="ok.gif" onclick="submit();" style="cursor: pointer;">
</form>
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? It is not working. I need it to be able to compare entered value named sn, with var pass.

I am noob and not a native speaker, so stay calm, please:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

#### Javascript

```
<script  language="JavaScript">
    function checkIt(){
        var pass = document.getElementById("sn").value;  
        if (pass == "1234")  
            {  
                alert("Please input a Value");  
                return false;  
            }  
        else   
            {  
                alert('Code has accepted : you can try another');  
                return true;   
            }  
    } 
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form1" onsubmit="return checkIt();">
    <input type="password" id="sn" name="sn" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
    <img src="ok.gif" onclick="document.getElementById("form1").submit();" style="cursor: pointer;">
</form>
```

Comment: I've just changed the last line

Comment: <input type="image" src="ok.gif" onclick="document.getElementById("form1").submit();" style="cursor: pointer;">

Comment: And if you do that, you do not need the click event! I explained everything in my post. Feel free to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your script

```
// to get the input value
var pass = document.getElementById("sn").value;
```

And on your form you have to return the result of the function

```
onsubmit="return checkIt();"
```

Also remove `window.onload = checkIt();` that will validate the form before you enter any value

Answer (score 0):

Try `var pass = document.getElementById('sn').value;`

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="form1.submit()"` and `onsubmit="return checkIt()"`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function, not assigning it

```
window.onload = checkIt();
```

Needs to be

```
window.onload = checkIt;
```

But do you really want to run the validation when the page loads? You probably do not need this line at all. Delete it!

---

You are not cancelling the submit event. Your function returns true or false, but you are not handling it.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form1" onsubmit="checkIt();">
```

Your form tag needs to be

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form1" onsubmit="return checkIt();">
```

notice the return statement. That will cancel the submission.

---

What is `submit()`? The page is probably throwing an error which you would be able to see in the console. You need to tell it what to submit. That means referencing a form.

```
<img src="ok.gif" onclick="submit();" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

There is no method called `submit()` in your code. Maybe you want to call the form submission.

```
<img src="ok.gif" onclick="doucment.form1.submit();" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

You would probably be better off using input with `type="image"` to submit the form.

```
<input type="image" src="ok.gif" />
```

Using the input means no JavaScript is needed to submit the form. So remove the image tag and add the input element!

---

And finally you are reading the value of the form, not the input

```
var pass = document.form1.value;
```

You want the input!

```
var pass = document.form1.sn.value;
```

And it makes no sense why 1234 would fail, but all other things pass. Don't you have the logic wrong?

You need to learn how to debug, use the browser's console and learn to use console.log() to see the data. Set break points and walk through the code so you can inspect what is going on. JavaScript 101.

Comment: Learn to use debugging tools, you have tons of issues, you need to start with each little piece and work your way up. `console.log()` is your friend, use it.

Comment: @user2451963 So my answer tells you everything that is wrong and how to fix it. You should learn why the one you selected as an answer works.